# Ansible can't load variable from vars_files

Tags: ansible

i use this version of Ansible :

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ychtourou/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
```

and i've this small playbook :

```
- name: play create users from var file
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files: "vars/users.yaml"
  tasks:
  - name: group exists
    group:
      name: "{‌{ grp }}"
      state: present
  - name: user exists
    user:
      name: "{‌{ user }}"
      uid: "{‌{ id }}"
      state: present
      groups: "{‌{ grp }}"
      append: yes
```

the users.yaml file

```
user: qmerlin
id: 1000
grp: ops
```

the location of playbook and users.yaml file :

```
.
├── inventory
├── playbook1.yml
└── vars
    └── users.yaml
```

when execute using this command `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook1.yml --ask-become-pass` i get this error :

```
BECOME password: 

PLAY [play create users from var file] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1]

TASK [group exists] **********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "groupadd: '{‌{ grp }}' is not a valid group name\n", "name": "{‌{ grp }}"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************
server1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

it's look that Ansible is unable to get value from the file

how i can resolve that  ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have somehow introduced the character [`ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`](https://unicode-table.com/en/200C/) into your playbook. If you examine your playbook with `vim`, you'll see:

```
    - name: group exists
      group:
        name: "{<200c>{ grp }}"
        state: present
    - name: user exists
```

(Where `<200c>` represents the character in question)

That extra character means you don't have a Jinja `{{` template
marker, so you're not getting any variable substitution.

If I remove the erroneous characters from your playbook, it runs as
expected.

Comment: yes , it's work , like a charm , thanks ,